# how i get 5 digit after point in float variable?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium Studio. I need start 5 digit after point in float variable. how i get?

Example : var x = 25.50505055555;
i have need x = 25.50505;

(note : floating point may be increase or decrease.)
plz help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess Titanium studio is using javascript. Try this:

```
num = 25.50505055555;
result = num.toFixed(5);
```